# Using \parbox in \resizebox

Tags: spacing, macros, boxes

I tried resizing a `\parbox`-d text into a `5cm x 5cm` square box (without keeping the aspect ratio). The output is absolutely strange to me, even if I don't specify the height. Couldn't find the cause/culprit. Why does the output happen to be this? Is there a way to do this somehow?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\resizebox{5cm}{!}{\parbox{20cm}{\lipsum{1}}}
\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=5cm]{}

\newpage

\resizebox{5cm}{5cm}{\parbox{20cm}{\lipsum{1}}}
\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=5cm]{}

\end{document}
```

I've some tried some possibilities like `\parbox[t][][t]...` but the output was even worse that way.

Comment: The `\parbox` is, by default, centered on the baseline, whereas the `\includegraphics` sits on the baseline. Try `\parbox[b]`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Thank you, this is the answer. I've tried several settings, but I didn't really knew what I was doing.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes You should turn that in to a real answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the default vertical alignment is different for `\parbox` and `\includegraphics`.  By default, the `\parbox` is centered vertically about the baseline.  The `\includegraphics` always sits atop the baseline.

In the first graphic below, I show the problem that you were trying to fix, with the baseline given for reference.  In the second image, I show that by using a `[b]` option on the `\parbox`, you can achieve bottom alignment, as you desired.

In the third image, I show that, for those times where you need to achieve top alignment on a graphic, you can use the `\belowbaseline` feature of the `stackengine` package to achieve it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\baseline{\rule{2cm}{.1ex}}
\parskip 1cm
\begin{document}
BASELINE:
\baseline
\parbox{2cm}{This should be a centered parbox, by default}
\baseline
\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{}
\baseline

BASELINE:
\baseline
\parbox[b]{2cm}{This should be a bottom-justified parbox}
\baseline
\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{}
\baseline

BASELINE:
\baseline
\parbox[t]{2cm}{This should be a top-justified parbox}
\baseline
\belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{}}
\baseline
\end{document}
```

[image]